# Javascript does not work on Safari browser real devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have a scenario where i need to enter email and click on submit button but when webdriver enters email and clicks on submit button an error is thrown "Email is Required" although webdriver entered the email which i can see. I have this issue on Firefox and Safari both on Desktop and mobile devices. With a bit of research i able to fix for Firefox with below javascript code.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
js.executeScript("var e=document.getElementById('email'); e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); e.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur')); return true;" );
```

But the same code does not work on mobile safari on real device. Could someone help in fixing this issue ?

Environment

```
 Appium version - 1.6.5 Mac os : 10.12.6 Node.js version - 3.10.10
 Mobile platform/version under test: - 10.3 Iphone 6 Real device Using
 Appium desktop client Logs: <script
 src="https://gist.github.com/mahesh-thuma/f02f6fdc81d48d4c0a16e2dd71412e0c.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. There is a small change in the email attribute from desktop ("`email`") to mobile ("`Email`"). Modified the javascript accordingly and i am able to proceed ahead. Though this is still an workaround but does the job. Closing this issue and Thanks to anyone investing time on this.

Answer (score 0):

import Page from './page';

class YahooPage extends Page  {
    /**
     * define elements
     */

```
get searchInput()   { return browser.element('#yschsp'); }
get searchButton()  { return browser.element('//div[@class="mag-glass"]'); }
get resultsList()   { return browser.element('#results'); }

/**
 * define or overwrite page methods
 */

open () {
    super.open('https://search.yahoo.com')       //provide your additional URL if any. this will append to the baseUrl to form complete URL
    browser.pause(1000);
}

enterText (item) {
    this.searchInput.clearElement();
    this.searchInput.setValue(item);
}

search () {
    this.searchButton.click();
}
isSearched () {
    this.resultsList.waitForVisible(1000);
    return this.resultsList.isVisible();
}
```

}

export default new YahooPage();`enter code here`